# counting up/down the number of the comment based on its number in the list

Tags: php

```
while($qry_comment = mysql_fetch_array($sql_comment)) {
echo "#1,";
echo $qry_comment['content'];
echo "<br />";
}
```

i'm trying to make the number count up in the while loop,
but i just don't know how.
something with ++ , i tried a few ways but I couldn't make it work the right way.
can anyone help me out here?
thanks

Comment: Do you want to display each comment's number next to the comment, or do you want to count the total number of comments?

Comment: i got the number next to it. how can i make it count the total?

Comment: By the way, [you shouldn't use mysql_ functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1001110). Use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead.

Comment: can you suggest me a link to an easy and understandable guide for mysqli or pdo?

Comment: I don't have a specific guide, but if you search Google for 'pdo beginners guide' or something like that, you'll find a lot of results.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a variable that increments on each loop iteration:

```
$counter = 1;
while($qry_comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_comment)) {
  echo "#" . $counter . ",";
  echo $qry_comment['content'];
  echo "<br />";
  $counter++;
}
```

Comment: it jumps by two all the time, why?

Comment: Because `mysql_fetch_array` retrieves both a numerical and associative based array. Try using `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead. (See my edit above)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to increase the value of a variable with 1:

[Arithmetic operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

- `$a = $a + 1;`
- `$a += 1;`

[Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

- `$a++;`
- `++$a;`

The location of the incrementing / decrementing operator determines when the calculation is executed. When using a pre-increment (`++$a;`), the variable is incremented, then returned. When using a post-increment (`$a++;`), the variable is returned first, and then incremented.

Example:

```
$a = 5;
echo $a++; // echoes '5'
echo $a;   // echoes '6'

$a = 5;
echo ++$a; // echoes '6'
echo $a;   // still echoes '6'
```

Of course, if you don't echo the value, it doesn't matter if you use `$a++` or `++$a`.

Returning to your case, you can use the following code:

```
$counter = 1;

while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_comment)) {
    echo '#' . $counter++ . ','; // First echo $counter, then increment it
    echo $comment['content'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

By the way, [you can use MySQL instead of PHP to count the comments as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769415/1001110).