# How to use mysql variables in doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12772507/1507546

I want to execute this query through doctrine but I'm getting the error below

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>     '@counter := 0' at line 1

Here is my code

```
$sql = <<<S
    SET @counter = 0; 
    Select sub.orderid,sub.value,(@counter := @counter +1) as counter
    FROM
    (
        select orderid, 
          round(sum(unitprice * quantity),2) as value
        from order_details
        group by orderid
    ) sub
    order by 2 desc
    limit 10
S;

stmt = $this->_em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

return $stmt->fetchAll(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Try adding the `SET` in another statement. Most sql APIs don't allow multiple statements in a single query without extra configuration.

Comment: Right thank! You can post your answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most sql APIs don't allow multiple statements without extra configuration. You'll need to pass them in as separate statements:

```
$this->_em->getConnection()->exec("SET @counter = 0"); // May need tweaking, I'm not familiar with Doctrine
$sql = <<<S
    Select sub.orderid,sub.value,(@counter := @counter +1) as counter
    FROM
    (
        select orderid, 
          round(sum(unitprice * quantity),2) as value
        from order_details
        group by orderid
    ) sub
    order by 2 desc
    limit 10
S;

stmt = $this->_em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: You can use `SQLSessionInit` to trigger random SQL query just after the effective first connexion