# Typo3 LTS9 Doctrine: How to use mysql @-Variables?

Tags: mysql, variables, select, doctrine, typo3

What's the right way to execute the following typo3 SELECT with mysql @-variables:

```
$dbConnection = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionForTable($extensionTable);
$queryBuilder = $dbConnection->createQueryBuilder();

$query = $queryBuilder
->select('extensionTable.*',
'@dist:=ACOS(ROUND(SIN(RADIANS(geo.coord_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(52.5234743092278))
   + COS(RADIANS(geo.coord_lat)) * COS(RADIANS(52.5234743092278))
   * COS(RADIANS(geo.coord_lon)      - RADIANS(13.4122033308763)),10)) * 6380 AS distance',
'@distgrp:=CASE WHEN @dist <10 THEN 1 WHEN @dist<25 THEN 2 ELSE truncate(((@dist-25)/25)+3, 0) END AS dist_group')
->from('extensionTable  LEFT JOIN geoTable AS geo ON geo.zip=extensionTable.zip')
->where('pid IN (15,16)');
```

It's not working, typo3 is inserting a ' before the @dist var. The **bad result** is:

```
SELECT 'extensionTable'.*, '@dist:=... ' AS 'distance';
```

> **Error**: An exception occurred while executing... You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Related topic (solution doesn't work with $queryBuilder->select() ): 
[How to use mysql variables in doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267560/how-to-use-mysql-variables-in-doctrine)

I hope someone can help me. :-) (Or do I have to use a direct php mysqli() query.)

Comment: I would calculate `dist_group` in PHP. Even if you get this SQL to run - this way is not reliable. There is no guarantee that `@dist` will be calculated before `dist_group`.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel: I use this select with mysql for many years. It's working fine and dist is calculated before dist_group.

Comment: "I use this select with mysql for many years. It's working fine" .. until it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent escaping with a `selectLiteral`.

```
$queryBuilder
  ->select(...)
  ->addSelectLiteral('@dist:=COS(RADIANS(90))')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the solution. You saved my day! :-)